# console.log to a custom category

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

I have a requirement to display all the logs with a tag (say TelemetryLogs) to a group, so that I can see all the network calls flow in a single view.

The requirement is to see the Network Calls in a grouped view - say a table with key-name , key-type and log-object.

The immediate suggestion that we gave to business is that we would log to console with a prefix and allow them to filter using a filter-expression.
Eg: ``` console.log(``Telemetry %s %s %o``, "name", "type", { someobject: 'someval' }) ```

But they want the group to appear as a sub-group under one-of the categories in chrome (pic below).  Apparently, they plan to roll out similar groups and dont want to remember a list of expression, to filter out what they want.

I then realized stackoverflow is the right place to check if this is possible, if not possible, what other grouped display options would help us achieve a similar expectation.

Note: Background of the use-case is that during our pair-programming, sometimes we end up business analyst sitting next to us.  One of them realized if they had a consolidated-running-view of the telemetry data  during development, it would help him/her catch early issues...

[image]

Comment: _"I then realized stackoverflow is the right place to check if this is possible"_ - The right place is the documentation of the browser you're going to use and if this browser supports such a thing as "custom groups" -> [Console Overview  |  Tools for Web Developers  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console)

Comment: [Unfortunately, the documentation does not seem to indicate any such option.](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/log)

Comment: The best you might be able to do, if you have a direct workflow you're targeting, is to `group` at the start and `groupEnd` at the end, but that will affect *all* logging. Client-side logging is very limited, which is why real logging goes back to the server--this should be trivially traceable on the server side anyway.

Comment: @DaveNewton : U are right.. we do have kibana visualizers at the server side. this is for development monitor during pair programming... the logs take approx 3 to 5 minutes to appear in the visualizer

Comment: i ve checked out on `group` , but that does the job only in when done in a sequential code block.. The telemetry logs are asynchronous and the control go back and forth between code...

Comment: @Raghav Don't use Kibana during debugging, use regular logging. In any case, the best you'll be able to do is either log meaningful text (either manually or via a logging package) or store up data somewhere and dump it at the "end". You can color/style log messages as well, which can be helpful for spotting "related" console output.

Comment: @Andreas: thats an awesome eye-opener.. i totally forgot about browser documentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no way to create sub groups in the console current API [standard](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#console-namespace) that appear in the developer tools panel - there are group related functions that can group multiple log statements under one statement but thats not what you want, anyway here are two options that came to my mind

- structure you log messages in a way that they can be easily filtered using the built in filter for logs maybe something of the following nature (groupId - logType - message) (Anyway it is always better to have a structure for logs)
- The developer tools are part of the page, and they can have custom extended functionalities, you can create an extension that adds subgroups to that panel, along with the functionality you need, or you can add a tab of your own to filter that logs (its easier that what it looks)

Anyway one important thing to note, is that if logs are important to you then they should be sent to an external service that ensures no data is lost, and enables advanced load and extract functionalities on the logs. And anyway logs on the client side in the console are only useful for development, so is it worth it ?